# jQuery Ideal Forms Validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, idealforms

I am using idealforms.js to validate my fields. On drop-down change I am adding Rule to existing validation so 1 extra field called my_box can be validated. The filed becomes required but after drop down change I am pushed to step 1 and have to manually switch back to step 5:

Code:

```
$('#employment_details').change(function() {
  $('form').idealforms('addRules', {
    'my_box': 'required'
  });       
});
```

(Please go to step 3 and select drop down) Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymfvqyob/4/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ymfvqyob/4/

Comment: JS Fiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/ymfvqyob/4/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

```
$('#employment_details').change(function() {
  $('form').idealforms('addRules', {
    'my_box': 'required'
  });
  $('form.idealforms').idealforms('goToStep', 5);       
});
```